# How do I solve caching problems such as cache invalidation and data race in a monolithic app?

Tags: caching

When creating a distributed web application, cache invalidation can be a big deal. However, our web application doesn't need distributed load, as we don't expect to serve more than 1k users at a time. For now, we've had a multithreaded asynchronous web application written in Rust. The web application is run on only one instance.

We're not using Redis. What's the common cache invalidation strategies for such app?

Comment: It can be a big deal, but it can also be irrelevant.  The core of the issue is that you generally cannot know what problems even need solving until you've already implemented something (It is a waste of time to think about hypothetical scenarios, and an even bigger waste of time to try to solve hypothetical problems.  If you cannot observe and test a problem then the problem doesn't meaningfully exist).  The only 'best' solution is not to implement caching until you have a need for it.   Once you've implemented it, then you can start to look at whether there are any problems that need solving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> common cache invalidation strategies

There are two hard problems in computer science:
naming, caching, and off-by-one.

It's unclear what compute resources your caching hopes to conserve,
and what cost function applies for "stale" results.
If RAM resident set size is the concern, then a
[LRU cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)
would be the typical response.

If users find that results rapidly lose their value over time,
then it is customary to impose a Time To Live of e.g. 120 seconds,
discarding cached results once their TTL has expired.

> The [current] web application is run on only one instance.

If and when you scale out horizontally, you may want to
install a Load Balancer between servers and clients,
which hashes on client IP so all of a given client's
requests usually go to a single server.
Then you are largely back in your current position,
and each server instance is free to manage its cache as it sees fit,
with little worry about cache inconsistencies across servers.

If you want to approach this in a more methodical way,
assign dollar amounts to the costs of caching "too much"
(perhaps in customer attrition due to low quality result pages)
versus the costs of caching "too little"
(perhaps in customer attrition due to sluggish response times,
or perhaps in higher hosting fees from horizontal scale-out).